# How to put data to an MEdit box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the output of my program to be sent to an MEdit box but for whatever reason the html method does not set the value of the box should I use an MLabel instead?

here is my code:

function MButton1Click(event)
{

```
var temp = $("#MEdit1").val();
temp = parseInt(temp);
var selectedItem = $("input[name='MRadioGroup1']:checked").val();

if(selectedItem == 0)
{
    var five9ths = 5/9;
    temp = temp - five9ths;
    temp = temp + 32;       
    $('#MEdit3').html("C");
}
else
{
    var nine5ths = 9/5;
    temp = temp * nine5ths;
    temp = temp + 32;
    $('#MEdit3').html("F");
}
    var temperature = temp.toString();
    $('#MEdit2').html(temperature);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

```
$('#MEdit3').val("C");
```

Here is what your code should look like :

```
function MButton1Click(event) {
    var temp = $("#MEdit1").val();
    temp = parseInt(temp);
    var selectedItem = $("input[name='MRadioGroup1']:checked").val();

    if (selectedItem == 0) {
        var five9ths = 5 / 9;
        temp = temp - five9ths;
        temp = temp + 32;
        $('#MEdit3').val("C");
    } else {
        var nine5ths = 9 / 5;
        temp = temp * nine5ths;
        temp = temp + 32;
        $('#MEdit3').val("F");
    }
    var temperature = temp.toString();
    $('#MEdit2').val(temperature);
}
```